# Laravel 5.5 | Redirect main domain to public folder

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes, laravel-5.5

I have `laravel 5.5` project uploaded to live hosting on `/public_html/commerce`.

When I go to `domain.com/commerce/public` then everything looks working perfectly.

But when I point the `domain` directly to `commerce/public`, so; when I visit `domain.com` then all links got broken like this:

`domain.com/product/domain.comget-item-sizes-detail`

Route for above link:

`Route::post('/get-item-sizes-detail', 'ProductController@getItemSizesDetail');`

Ajax request:

`url:'get-item-sizes-detail',
type:"POST",
dataType:"JSON"`

Any suggestions?

Comment: which function you have used to generate the link?

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni `Route::post('/get-item-sizes-detail', 'ProductController@getItemSizesDetail');`

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni it's an Ajax request `url:'get-item-sizes-detail',
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"JSON"`

Comment: You have to give full path in ajax request too.
use `url()` or `route()` function inside blade.

Comment: Is your Ajax call is in seperate js file?

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni Some inside view and others in separate JS file.

Comment: I'll suggest if the `url` is inside blade file then use the laravel helper functions,
and if you need it in some js file then read the `url` from blade file.
some suggestions would be to 
1) initialize a JavaScript variable inside a blade file and using it inside js file,
2) use custom html tags to retain the url value and read those tags inside the js file.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix:

1. Create a folder in your public_html directory
   I will call it `webroot` you can call it anything you want.
2. Put all the content of your Laravel `public` folder inside `public_html` directory
3. Put all other remaining files and folder of your Laravel project inside `webroot`
4. Edit `public_html/index.php`, change line 22 `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';` to `require __DIR__.'/webroot/bootstrap/autoload.php';` and change line 36 `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` to `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/webroot/bootstrap/app.php';`

So you don't have to point your main domain to public_html/public again.
Just accessing the `maindomain.com` should have your project running just like using PHP `artisan serve`. But still using a service like Forge or Fortrabbit is the best way to host your Laravel app.

Good luck

Comment: its going to be okay, but css and js file path issue. can you tell me. what will be the css and js file path.?

Comment: I would advise you use this for your CSS and JS links: 
`URL::asset('path/to/your/cssOrJsAssets')` . This way, you don't have to modify your assets link. Do it for images also.